# Get the button value from semantic ui react

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am a newbie to React.Currently I am facing this problem.

Here is my code

```
    handleClick(e) {
       console.log('Click happened'+" "+ e.target.value);//getting UNDEFINED here
   }
```

In the below code locationArr contains many locations

```
{ locationArr.map((location) => {
     console.log(location); //It prints all the locations here NO PROBLEM 
     if (location !== ' ') {
       return (
        <div className ="ui stackable four column grid">
         <div className="column centered">
         </div>
         <div className="column">
         </div>
         <div className="column centered">
           <Button size='huge' primary  value='{location}' as={Link} 
            to="/location" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} >
               {location} // ABLE TO GET LOCATION NAMES here 
           </Button>
```

Now my problem is I want to access the value of the location from the button in handleClick function and I also need to pass it to another component.Anyone please suggest me how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}` to

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(location)}
```

Working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fafdha)

Demo solves your both problems.

Comment: See this line <Hello name={this.state.name} /> in demo . click button you can see text changes  from React to  ButtonTextHere

Comment: Check the demo now , and explore your codes in that demo and  i'll take a look on it then